# Adding path of counties to state I have projected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have the state of Missouri projected, I just need to add a path of the counties. I know there is a way to use `.enter` and add another path I am just not sure how.

[image]
I have the mo-counties.json downloaded can I do something like:

```
.enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
    .style('fill', 'silver')
    .style('stroke', 'white')
    .style('stroke-width', 1);
```

or can I use the projection I already have to overlay the counties?

This is what I have:

```
d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var feature = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states)
    .features
    .filter(function(d) {  return d.id == 29; })[0]; 


  var projection = d3.geoIdentity()
    .fitSize([400,400],feature); 

  path.projection(projection);
```

In the future I am looking to color each county darker or lighter according to population with data stored in a csv, how can I connect that data I have to each county?

[Here](https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/us-states/MO-29-missouri-counties.json) is the link to the counties json file.

Comment: Your state geojson/topojson uses already projected coordinates. We need to ascertain what coordinate system your county data uses in order to be able to align county and state - if they use the same coordinate system, you can reuse the path generator - but I highly doubt this is the case. Chances are your county data is in 3D coordinate space comprised of lat long points while your state data is in a 2D coordinate space measured in pixels with a transform applied (due to fitSize), which gives us a few options, but before I assume this is the case, can you share a link to the counties data?

Comment: I added the link to where I got counties information but I know scaling will be an issue so I was wondering if there is an easier way. I don't need to use the other file. I know d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json contains county outlines I just want to add them over top. @AndrewReid Thanks!